# Upload file in FTP server by using progress bar with C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, file-upload, ftp

I have to upload a huge file in FTP server and using progress bar.

How can i perform this without using any third free components?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this proper only with plain ASP.NET. For the state of the progress bar you'll need some JavaScrip/AJAX action or a Flash object. If you don't want to go with a free 3rd party component, you need to write it by yourself. There's no build-in ASP.NET functionality.

**Update**

Since the use of AJAX is a possibility for you, this article might be interesting:

- [Real-Time Progress Bar With ASP.NET AJAX](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/RealTime_Progress_Bar_With_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx)

Comment: Indeed you can write a progress bar using ASP.NET only (with a lot of postbacks), but it will be very ugly, however.

Comment: @abatishchev: I would never recommend that, but generally you are right.

Comment: Perefct i have no probem to use AJAX.

Comment: Agree. That's definitely bad idea

Answer (score 0):

You can get a code to specify the size of the file already in the server and bind it to a timer. Then, based on the file size of the file being uploaded, you will be able to deduce the size already uploaded.

I'll get you the code, but I'd suggest you get them on separate threads as they will slow down the system considerably.